# No matches found for contact reference field in front end profile

Tags: profile

Duplicated on Wp and Drupal Demo sites
Custom field of type contact reference used in front end profile for search and listings (public)
Search returns “no matches found” even though contact name appears in field
Logged in as admin
[image]

Entering nothing in search fields and pressing search lists all contacts in database. I don't get why a single contact from the contact reference field is "no match"
[image]

Comment: Just tried reproducing on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org - Advanced Search works correctly finding by contact ref.  Please describe in more detail how you are searching.

Comment: It's nothing to do with advanced search it's a front end profile.  This is the url - logged in as admin on wordpress demo site http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile&gid=16&reset=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please check if Adams, Lou is saved in custom field for any contact in your system? The profile search that you have created will list all the contacts having Adams, Lou saved in their respective custom field.

I guess you trying to create a profile search that will list details of a contact by selecting contact from a drop down.

Comment: Yes I do want to create a profile search that will list details of a contact by selecting contact from a drop down. If I don't enter anything in the search fields, all the contacts in the database are listed

Comment: Nothing to do with Lou Adams - select any contact from the drop down and it's "no matches Found"

Comment: Its a contact reference custom field for a contact and NOT actual contact reference field. Definitely when you dont enter anything it means no criteria is being applied and it will show all results. To make you understand more try updating a contact and have the custom field set to different contact and then perform profile search. You should get results

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you very much Pradeep. So is there anyway to achieve a profile search that will list details of a contact by selecting contact from a drop down?

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as answered and vote if you feel i was very useful?